# overlay rasters at a given value

Tags: r, overlay, gis, raster, r-raster

I am relatively new to using `R` and working with GIS data.

I am trying to create a function to overlay two `Raster` layers, only when one of the rasters (in this case `raster1`) is at a certain value (in this case 0). I have tried numerous options in doing this but they don't seem to work. My last attempt is provided below, and it runs but the output just says `NULL` and it does not plot.

```
library(raster)

raster1 <- raster(ncols=10,nrows=10) 
raster2 <- raster(ncols=10,nrows=10) 

values(raster1) <- round(runif(ncell(raster1)))
values(raster2) <- round(runif(ncell(raster2)))

plot(raster1)
plot(raster2)

overlay_zero <- function (x, y) {
if (isTRUE(x == 0)) {
  overlay(x, y, fun=function(x,y) {return(x+y)})}
} 


z <- overlay_zero(raster1, raster2)
z
plot(z)
```

Comment: So if I understood correct, at value `0` fo `raster1` you want to add the values of `raster2`?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
overlay_ras <- function(ras1,ras2,value=0){

  result              <- ras1
  result[ras1==value] <- ras1[ras1==value] + ras2[ras1==value]
  return(result)

}

overlaid <- overlay_ras(raster1,raster2,0)
```

This will do the trick. The function takes two rasters and a value which will be used to determine the cells affected by the overlay (addition).

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DfFinch Note: You should however only use it for smaller rasters.
Glad I could help. If you liked my answer, I would appreciate an upvote.