# How to find an intersection of two rasters with different ranges of continuous variables in r

Tags: r, gis, overlay, intersection, r-raster

I'm trying to use R to find intersections between ranges of rasters that represent different climate variables. The closest answer I can find is this: [overlay rasters at a given value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45009090/overlay-rasters-at-a-given-value)

For example, if I'm using the raster package to analyse [two bioclim variables](https://worldclim.org/data/worldclim21.html) (e.g. average temperature and precipitation), how can I find and plot places with a temperature range of 15-20 and a precipitation of 500-750?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal, self-contained, reproducible, example

```
library(raster)
temp <- prec <- raster()
values(temp) <- rep(1:30, each=ncell(temp)/30)
prec[,1:ncol(prec)] <- seq(0,nrow(prec)*10,10)
```

Solution

```
tr <- reclassify(temp, c(-Inf, 15, NA, 15, 20, 1, 20, Inf, NA))
pr <- reclassify(prec, c(-Inf, 500, NA, 500, 750, 1, 750, Inf, NA))
zone <- overlay(tr, pr, fun=function(x,y) x*y)
# zone <- tr * pr # is equivalent
```

or using 0 instead of NA

```
tr <- reclassify(temp, c(-Inf, 15, 0, 15, 20, 1, 20, Inf, 0))
pr <- reclassify(prec, c(-Inf, 500, 0, 500, 750, 1, 750, Inf, 0))
zoneTF <- tr & pr
```

And now you may want to do

```
s <- stack(prec, temp)
s <- mask(s, zone)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect - and sorry, I hadn't included sample code because I thought it would be easier to point to the closer answer I'd found previously. As a further question, is it possible to create the 'zone' object in such a way that it includes both the tr and pr layers, showing the intersection between the two variables as well as the variables themselves?

Comment: You can use `stack`, perhaps followed by `mask`. I have added that  to the answer.